# Using "Save As" execCommand in IE8 to save XML file in ANSI format instead of UCS2-Little Endian

Tags: javascript, encoding, internet-explorer-8, window.open

I am currently trying to save an XML data using "SaveAs" execCommand  from Javascript in Internet Explorer 8 only.I am using document.write(xml) to write the xml content after i open a window.The document object in IE8 uses a saveAs Exec Command to allow the user to save the xml file in the local folder.The XML file is generated but it doesnt set the encoding to my preferred type  for a different interface where i need to send this XML which is ANSI/UTF-8   encoding.I can only save the XML in UCS2 little Endian encoding format.Below is the code i am using.

```
 var location = "D:\\export_to_MCT"+dateTime+".xml";

    var xml = tmpSelectedConfigurationXML.transformNode(xslDoc);// XML Is generated here
   alert(xml);
     **var testlink = window.open  ("about:blank","_blank","toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none");
     testlink.document.write(xml); //fileData has contents for the file
testlink.document.close();
testlink.document.execCommand('SaveAs', false, location);**
testlink.close();
```

My purpose is to save the xml  in ANSI/UTF-8 encoding without BOM format.I cant use Scripting.FileSystemObject method of ActiveX object.Please suggest

Comment: Can anybody please suggest Something .it will be of great help

Answer (score 1):

Strip out unsupported characters from XML

Since not all UTF-8 characters are accepted in an XML document, you’ll need to strip any such characters out from any XML that you generate. 
After reading the xml file replace '/[^\x{0009}\x{000a}\x{000d}\x{0020}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}]+/u' with ''

or
try with
testlink.document.charset="UTF-8";

Comment: Sudha--I have pasted this question after trying many options by  myself ; and just because i guess you aint sure abt circumstances properly leading to the question,  it does not reflect the reasonableness of answering it and answering it anything